# Java Socket not honoring connect timeout

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to manually handle the connection timeout of a socket to a server. If the server does not reply in 1 second, I want to know that and try 3 more times right after.

The following are the main lines my code is based on:

```
// tcpSocket was previously declared, instantiate it
tcpSocket = new Socket();
try {
    // try to connect with a 1-second timeout
    tcpSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mRemoteAddr, mRemotePort), 1000);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
    // retry here... omissis
}
```

When the first connection (say, from local port `X`) is not accepted within 1000 milliseconds, I do get the `SocketTimeoutException` and the following connection succeeds (on a new local port, say `Y`).

But when reading the TCP packages with Wireshark I can see that, after 3-6-9-etc seconds, the **`X` connection is automatically retried**, as a new **`SYN`** package gets sent! I have even tried to put a `tcpSocket.close()` in the `catch` block of the `SocketTimeoutException`, but if the connection is not established, it cannot be closed (calling `close` does not lead to anything).

From what I understand, the wrong behaviour I'm seeing (which is, the automatic retrying of the connection) is correct if and only if I don't specify any timeout in the `connect` method.

Is this a bug, or is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the socket exists it can be closed, indeed it must be closed, regardless of whether the connect succeeded or not. I don't know where you got the idea that then connect can't be retried. Your question isn't clear. Do you mean that the SYNs are retried even after the timeout has expired?

Comment: Yes, `SYN` packages are retried (not by me, on the original port). I did close the socket, but it has no effect on those `SYN` packages, because I still see those.

Comment: On *nix, you can do an strace/ktrace to see what is going on at the kernel interface: `strace java <program>`

Comment: For example, an `strace nc -w 20000 localhost 5000` (netcat with connect timeout 20 secs)  revealed a non-blocking `connect()` call followed by a blocking `select()` call, which basically waits up to 20 secs for the [fd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to become available (`select(4, NULL, [3], NULL, {20000, 0})  = 1 (out [3], left {19999, 999998})`)